# Dell XPS 1330 / 1530 - Won't turn without power lead, but you can remove power lead once turned on?

Tags: power-supply, power, dell-xps

As the subject states, I can't turn on my dell xps 1330 without the power lead in. There is nothing from pressing the button.

It has a newish fully charged battery and have tried a couple of good ones.

Once I put the power lead in I can turn it on and I can remove the power lead and everything's fine?

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I've also noticed a flashing red battery icon on the front of the laptop when any of the 2 decent batteries are in there! Sounds like a shot charging component / motherboard?

Comment: Have you tried removing the battery (while it is _not_ plugged in) and putting it back in?

Comment: Yes tried that and pressed power whilst battery is out..

Comment: Update added above